# How may I print from a DosBox application to a wirelessly connected network printer?

Tags: wireless-networking, printing, printer, network-printer, dosbox

I'm using a Surface Pro 2 running Windows 10.  The DOS program from which to print is EZ-Tree, a genealogy application produced in 1987.  Its List function does the printing and is extremely limited.  Its configuration screen has nothing about printer configuration.  I'm assuming that it looks for LPT1.

My printer is a Brother HL-2270DW.  The port setting for it is WSDxxxxxxx and identified as a WSD port which somehow or other deals with 192.168.1.129.

This printing is going to be a singular event.  I'll use the paper copy to ease getting the data manually into a more standard application.  I'd even consider doing the print to FILE: to get a copy of the data that Windows (and I) can deal with.

Comment: If you are using the [SVN-Daum version of DOSBox](http://ykhwong.x-y.net/), you can capture the LPT output from DOSBOX into a file, and then manage the file how you please. I've been doing this for years on Windows 7; to go to a physical printer, I used [Peter Lerup's PrintFile](http://www.lerup.com/printfile). I don't believe that any of the other builds of DOSBox support printer emulation.

Answer (score 0):

On the PC, make sure that the printer is Shared. At a command line (cmd.exe) on Windows, issue the command:

NET USE LPT1: \\pc_name\printer_sharename /PERSISTENT:YES

From then on, any output to LPT1 will be redirected to the printer.

This will only work if your printer supports ASCII text. If your printer supports PCL5, that will work fine. Cheaper, host-based, printers do not support plain text and will not work.

Comment: DOSBOX seems not to support the NET command.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does it work if you use the NET command from CMD instead of in DOSBOX?

Comment: Very close.  After that, the configuration needs to be updated.... 

[parallel] #newline
parallel1: reallpt #end. Put it before autostart.  Restart dosbox afterward. The config file should be located in a subfolder in your home directory.  Search for "dosbox*.conf"